# Zend Framework 2 Dependency injection in a Filter

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I'm now trying to implement my own filter in ZF2.

However, I'm encountering a problem that I can't find a clear enough documentation about.

My filter needs to get **both the options array**(in my case, it contains `width` and `height` fields), and **a service locator instance**.

However, I can't manage to make it receive the `WebinoImageThumb` class instance.

Here's the filter code (here, `$this->serviceLocator` always remains NULL, which is the problem):

```
<?php

namespace Application\Form\Filter;

use Zend\Filter\Exception;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class FitImage extends \Zend\Filter\AbstractFilter implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $serviceLocator;

    private $width;
    private $height;
    private $thumbnailer;

    public function __construct($generalServiceLocator/*$options*/)
    {
        var_dump($generalServiceLocator);

        $width = $options['width'];
        $height = $options['height'];

        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;

        // We encourage to use Dependency Injection instead of Service Locator
        $this->thumbnailer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('WebinoImageThumb');
    }

    public function filter($value)
    {
        $thumb = $thumbnailer->create($value, $options = array(), $plugins = array());

        $thumb->resize($this->width, $this->height);

        $thumb->save($value);

        return $value;
    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }


    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
}
```

And I use it in a form like this:

```
<?php
namespace Backend\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class AuthorForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('author');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'portrait_file',
            'type' => 'file',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Портрет',
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Go',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'name' => 'portrait_file',
                'required' => false,
                'filters' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Application\Form\Filter\FitImage',
                        'options' => array(
                            'width' => 300,
                            'height' => 250
                        )
                    )
                ),
                // validators go here
            )
        );
    }
}
```

It seems that by implementing `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` the FitImage filter should receive the serviceLocator via `setServiceLocator`, but it does not.

What am I missing?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Injecting the service locator is a poor design strategy; a better approach would be to inject what the class needs, the `WebinoImageThumb` 'service'.

First remove the `ServiceLocator` references and add the new service as a constructor argument.

```
namespace MyModule\Filter;

class FitImage extends AbstractFilter
{    
    protected $thumbnailService;

    protected $height;

    protected $width;

    // Type hinting on 'ThumbnailServiceInterface' would mean you can swap
    // out the 'service' with another at a later date
    public function __construct(ThumbnailServiceInterface $thumbnailService, $height = 100, $width = 100)
    {
        $this->thumbnailService = $thumbnailService;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    public function filter($value)
    {
        $thumb = $this->thumbnailService->create($value);
        $thumb->resize($this->height, $this->width);
        $thumb->save($value);

        return $value;
    }

    public function setHeight($height) {
       $this->height = intval($height);
    }

    public function setWidth($width) {
        $this->width = intval($width);
    }

}
```

Then create a service factory to create the filter.

```
namespace MyModule\Filter;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class FitImageFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        // $serviceLocator here is the 'filter plugin manager'
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $options = $this->getOptions($serviceLocator);

        return new FitImage(
            $serviceManager->get('WebinoImageThumb'),
            $options['height'],
            $options['width']
        );
    }

    protected function getOptions(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        // This could be loaded from config
        return array('height' => 100, 'width' => 100);
    }
}
```

Lastly, add the reference to the module config or `Module.php` as below

```
public function getFilterConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyModule\Filter\FitImage' => 'MyModule\Filter\FitImageFactory',
        ),
    );
}
```

As a side note without knowing your specific project, you may want to consider moving your thumbnail creation out of the 'filter' into a separate service. Filters are designed to filter/modify the given input `$value` and return a formatted value.

Comment: AlexP, thanks for your answer!
Could you please update the code to show how to get the options from the input filter specification (which lies in AuthorForm)?

Comment: @Maksym The [`AbstractFilter`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Filter/AbstractFilter.php) has a `setOptions` method that actually checks for a 'setter' method for the options you pass in. Therefore, you should just be able to add a `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` and  be able to pass in 'height' and 'width' as options when you attach the filter to the form - I've updated this in my example and made the `__constructor`'s `$height` and `$width` have a default value, rather than be required.

Answer (score 0):

The input filter in your case is not instantiated by the service manager that's why you don't have an instance of service locator in there. To solve this problem you can create your filter object manually where you can access the service manager. Then, you can attach it to the filter chain of the input filter in your form.

### Updated

I found a solution for your problem. You can keep your code as it is. If you create your form from the controller then the following code snippet will work well for you (tested)

```
    $form = new AuthForm();
    $filterChain = $form->getInputFilter()->get('portrait_file')->getFilterChain();
    $filterChain->getPluginManager()->setServiceLocator($this->getServiceLocator());
```

As it turns out, the filter chain manages its filters with a plugins manager. By defualt, the plugins manager does not keep any service locator, so you can feel free to set one as I did in my example above. In your filter code, you can access the main service locator as following:

```
$mainServiceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator();
```

Comment: Is there a way to create the filter object NOT manually? I've got lots of other filters created the same way, and I'd love to keep them all together like they are now.

Also, I'm quite a newbie in ZF2, so I'd be really grateful if you could post as much sample code as possible. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I found a nice solution for your problem. I have updated my answer above.